# How to get results from a Postgresql function using EF Core?

Tags: c#, postgresql, asp.net-core, .net-core, plpgsql

My issue is *very very very* simple but I cannot accomplish this with EF Core using ASP.NET Core MVC. I am just trying to query using raw sql with EF core and return a set of rows.

I have a function created in my Postgresql called show() (for testing purposes)

[image]

I created the function with this code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.show()
    RETURNS SETOF city
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    VOLATILE
    PARALLEL UNSAFE
    COST 100    ROWS 1000 
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
       RETURN QUERY SELECT * FROM City;                                                     
 END;
$BODY$;
```

I have this in my C# Code:

```
var listOfCities = _context.Database.FromSqlRaw("SELECT public.show()").ToList();
```

Gives me error in the part `.FromSqlRaw`:

> 'DatabaseFacade' does not contain a definition for 'FromSqlRaw' and no
> accessible extension method 'FromSqlRaw' accepting a first argument of
> type 'DatabaseFacade' could be found (are you missing a using
> directive or an assembly reference?)

-I do not want to use any DbContext since it is a custom query that can return any object from a function.

- I know this can be accomplished just by using LINQ `_context.Cities.ToList()` but I am trying to test and learn how to use functions using raw sql WITH parameters and no parameters.

How do I solve this? can this be accomplished with EF core?

Comment: Do you have a `using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure` statement?

Comment: Yes but it is useless, I tried this `_context.Cities.FromSqlRaw` and no error but since `Cities` is a table from Context and I do not want to use a table for mapping, just a custom DTO. SInce I do not have a DTO so I used `.Database`. Maybe I do now know what I am doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use dbcontext.Database.FromSqlRaw since FromSqlRaw returns item list, you can only use Database.ExecuteSqlCommand with database.

You will have to create a special DTO for your function result, it should include ALL data properties that are selected in your db function

```
public class SpCityResult
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
      
        public string Name { get; set; }
       
         ....... and so on

     
}
```

All properties in this class should be the same name and type as it is in your function

add SpCityResult to db context

```
public virtual DbSet<SpCityResult> SpCityResults { get; set; }
......

modelBuilder.Entity<SpCityResult>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);
```

run code

```
var cities= _context.SpCityResults.FromSqlRaw("SELECT public.show()").ToList();
```

if your existing City model has the same properties as db function, you don't need to create an extra DTO.

you can try this

```
var cities= _context.Cities.FromSqlRaw("SELECT public.show()").ToList();
```

Comment: gives me this error `'Cannot create a DbSet for 'SpCityResult' because this type is not included in the model for the context.'` and I included it int he dbcontext, maybe it is bout not mapped issue?

Comment: @Bluares Try to remove [NotMapped] and let me know the result. and add to db context modelBuilder.Entity<SpCityResult>().HasNoKey().ToView(null);

Comment: ok ready, worked after trying to figure some stuff out and ur solution worked good.

Comment: `.HasNoKey` prevents creating table to Database right?

Comment: @Bluares , yes you are right. It is only for this.

Comment: @Bluares - when you call function that returns table, then usually call it from `from` clause should be preferred: `select * from public.show()`

Comment: @PavelStehule that is what I tried and worked too! yeppp ur right